# jQuery Highlighter Alternative

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface

I searched everywhere but is there an alternative for http://www.dailymarkup.com/

Comment: What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: What is it that you don't like about jQuery Highlighter?

Comment: Given the lack of response to the comments left on this question: voting to close as 'not a real question.'

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Syntax Highlighter](http://www.balupton.com/projects/jquery-syntaxhighlighter/) is a new one based on version 3 of [Alex Gorbatchev's Syntax Highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) - a really really really popular plain javascript syntax highlighter.

It supports such things as `code` and `pre` blocks, able to use classnames like `language-javascript` to indicate we want it to highlight, as well as wordwrap. Can be further customised by using the HTML5 data attribute `data-sh` or via specifying options at initialisation. A great stable choice which is updated regularly.